Julia - Quickly import method from package in module
In Julia, I want to use the Optimizer method from Gurobi in a module which I then use in a Julia script. Importing this method (either with the line using Gurobi: Optimizer or import Gurobi: Optimizer) takes between 50 and 70 seconds. Before importing it, I call some JuMP methods (maybe this already helps with some dependence of the Optimizer methods and reduces the time?)
Is there any way to make this import less time-consuming (hopefully below 20sec)?
To do this, I inspired myself with this question, and the page of the Julia documentation on Modules. Here is a reduced example of how I do my different calls for now:
# MyModule.jl
__precompile__()
module MyModule
    # not used in this example
    using JuMP: Model, set_time_limit_sec, set_silent, fix, @constraint, @variable, @objective, optimize! 
    using Gurobi: Optimizer

    create_model() = Model(Optimizer)
end

# script.jl
push!( LOAD_PATH, "./" )
using MyModule

m = MyModule.create_model()

In a first REPL, I include MyModule.jl (taking about a minute), and execute using .MyModule only to check if everything is right. Then, in Windows' command invite, I execute julia .\script.jl.
